# Could not find data file in a Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

I would like to seed some data using a temp rake file for production env.

```
.
├── assets
└── tasks
    └── temporary
        ├── languages.csv
        └── languages.rake
```

Running the rake task produces the following error, `No such file or directory`.

```
Language Database Initialization Completed
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./languages.csv
/home/li-xinyang/Desktop/XX_OpenNB/lib/tasks/temporary/languages.rake:7:in `read'
```

Code snippet below is my rake task,

```
require 'csv'

namespace :languages do
  desc 'Seed initial languages data with language & code'
  task init_data: :environment do
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      csv_str = File.read('./languages.csv')
      csv = CSV.new(csv_str).to_a
      csv.each do |lan_set|
        lan_code = lan_set[0]
        lan_str = lan_set[1]
        Language.new(language: lan_str, code: lan_code).save
        print '.'
      end
    end
    puts 'Language Database Initialization Completed'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use something like this:

```
csv_str = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/tasks/temporary/languages.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

The file path should not use relative path

```
  csv_path = File.expand_path('languages.csv', File.dirname(__FILE__))
  csv_str = File.read(csv_path)
```